# Fullcalendar refetchEvents does not work (AJAX)

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, codeigniter, fullcalendar

Pressing the btn_insert button saves the form data to my DB, but the data is not updated on the calendar screen. I'm using .fullCalendar ('refetchEvents') but it does not work. If I reload the page, the calendar data is updated. The controller and the model have no errors, but I also put them in case it is necessary; I think the problem is found in Javascript. I hope you can help me, thank you all.

PD: My English is not very good, I hope you can understand

Controller

```
<?php

//We show the events

public function geteventos() {


    $r = $this->mCalendar->geteventos();
    echo json_encode($r);
}

public function insertar_cita() {

//we insert the events
    $data = array(
        'rut_usu' => $this->input->post('rut_usu'),
        'rut_estu' => $this->input->post('rut_estu'),
        'id_mot' => $this->input->post('id_mot'),
        'fecha_ini' => $this->input->post('fecha_ini'),
        'fecha_ter' => $this->input->post('fecha_ter'),
    );

    $this->load->model('mCalendar');
    $this->mCalendar->insertar_cita($data);
}
?>
```

Model

```
<?php

public function geteventos() {


//We show the events

    $this->db->select('CONCAT(estudiantes.pnombre," ", estudiantes.apellido_pa," ", estudiantes.apellido_ma,", ",motivos_citas.descripcion_mot) As title ,citas.id_ci id, citas.fecha_ini start, citas.fecha_ter end');
    $this->db->from('citas');
    $this->db->join('estudiantes', 'citas.rut_estu = estudiantes.rut_estu');
    $this->db->join('motivos_citas', 'citas.id_mot = motivos_citas.id_mot');
    $this->db->join('usuarios', 'citas.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu');
//$this->db->where('usuarios.rut_usu=17811942');

    return $this->db->get()->result();
}

public function insertar_cita($data) {

    /we insert the events
    $this->db->insert('citas', $data);
}
?>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //---------------------Full Calendar--------------------------------------
        $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>cCalendar/geteventos',
                function (data) {

                    //alert(data); 

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
                        },

                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                        businessHours: true, // display business hours
                        editable: true,
                        events: $.parseJSON(data),

                        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

                            date_last_clicked = $(this);
                            $(this).css('background-color', '#bed7f3');
                            $('#modal_registrar').modal();

                        },

                        minTime: "08:30:00",
                        maxTime: "23:00:00"

                    });


                });

        //--------------END  fullcalendar-----------------

        //---INSERT-----------------------------

        $("#btn_insert").click(function () {

            var rut_usu = $("#rut_usu").val();
            var rut_estu = $("#rut_estu").val();
            var id_mot = $("#id_mot").val();
            var fecha_ini = $("#fecha_ini").val();
            var fecha_ter = $("#fecha_ter").val();


            $.ajax({

                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "cCalendar/insertar_cita/",
                type: 'post',
                data: {"rut_usu": rut_usu, "rut_estu": rut_estu, "id_mot": id_mot, "fecha_ini": fecha_ini, "fecha_ter": fecha_ter},

                success: function (response) {

                    $("#modal_registrar").modal('hide');
                    $("#modal_confirmar").modal('show');
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');


                }

            });

        });

        //---END Insert-----------------------------

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try checking the Javascript console in your web browser if there are any errors or messages being displayed.

Comment: dashboard.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (dashboard.js:13)
    at i (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)

Comment: You should add the console output to the question.

Comment: I doubt that's the problem, that's because of the design ...

Comment: Is `$("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');` being executed?

Comment: refetch events doesn't work because you have a static events list (loaded via a JS variable). If you defined your `events` as a URL to server script which loads events, then it would work. Currently you load the events from the server, then display the calendar, and give the calendar what it thinks is a static list of events. It has no info about how to refetch them from the server. Another different way to put your new event onto the calendar during the btn_insert method is client-side using the fullCalendar renderEvent method, instead of doing a refetchEvents from the server.

Comment: Then how should I do it?

Comment: If you know how you could put your answer with the example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you could do this:

1) Insert the event into fullCalendar on the client-side using the renderEvent method.

(N.B. I don't know what your field names are, since they're not named in English, so I have guessed. Apologies if the names do not match the English ones - you can re-arrange them).

```
$("#btn_insert").click(function () {

  var rut_usu = $("#rut_usu").val();
  var rut_estu = $("#rut_estu").val();
  var id_mot = $("#id_mot").val();
  var fecha_ini = $("#fecha_ini").val();
  var fecha_ter = $("#fecha_ter").val();


  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "cCalendar/insertar_cita/",
    type: 'post',
    data: {"rut_usu": rut_usu, "rut_estu": rut_estu, "id_mot": id_mot, "fecha_ini": fecha_ini, "fecha_ter": fecha_ter},
    success: function (response) {
      $("#modal_registrar").modal('hide');
      $("#modal_confirmar").modal('show');
      //render an event object direct to the calendar
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', { "id", id_mot, "title": rut_usu + " " + rut_estu, "start": fecha_ini, "end", fecha_ter true);
    }
  });
});
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/

2) currently, "refetchEvents" doesn't work because you have a static events list (loaded via a JS variable). If you defined your events as a URL to server script which loads events, then it would work. At the moment, fullCalendar has no information with which to speak to the server to get the events.

You can change it like this, which is much more how fullCalendar expects you to load events:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
  },
  defaultDate: new Date(),
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  businessHours: true, // display business hours
  editable: true,
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>cCalendar/geteventos',
      { "start": start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"), "end": end.format("YYYY-MM-DD") },
      function (data) {
        callback($.parseJSON(data));
    });
  },
  dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
    date_last_clicked = $(this);
    $(this).css('background-color', '#bed7f3');
    $('#modal_registrar').modal();
  },
  minTime: "08:30:00",
  maxTime: "23:00:00"
});
```

Once you do that, in the "btn_insert" method, you can either continue to use refetchEvents, or you can still change as I suggested in (1) above, which avoids the extra ajax call to the server which is caused by using "refetchEvents".

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/

N.B. Ideally when you do this, you should change your PHP geteventos() method so that it accepts the "start" and "end" date parameters provided by fullCalendar, and then use them in the SQL, to return only the events for the current time period displayed on the calendar. Usually, once you have a lot of events in your database, this is more efficient than loading them all at once, as you do now. In my example I've already added code to send those dates as part of your ajax request to geteventos().

Comment: My hero,  <3 , Thank you